# Why does "hall of cat" sound incorrect, while "hall of cats" sounds correct (and similar)

Tags: nouns, word-usage

I am hoping to find rules that determine which nouns are acceptable in plural and singular form in the following sentence. I suspect this might be largely a matter of taste.

> hall of

I notice that some nouns work in either:

> hall of diamond / hall of diamonds

Others only singular:

> hall of blood

Others only plural as in the title, and where there is only a plural form:

> hall of clothes

Comment: Apart from ***hall of mirrors*** and metaphoric ***hall of fame*** we don't often refer to a hall of *anything* in English, so it's not a very good example to be asking which phrasing is most "natural". A "hall of cats" sounds just as weird to me as a "hall of **the** cat" (but without the article, the singular form would be even *weirder*).

Answer (score 1):

There is no grammatical rule; it depends on whether the phrase makes sense. I don't know what a 'hall of cat/cats' would be. A 'hall of diamonds' could be a big room decorated with diamonds or something (such as cut glass) that looks like them, but 'hall of diamond' doesn't sound right to me.

Compare the Hall of Mirrors at Versailles (contains many mirrors) and a Hall of Fame (an exhibition about famous people).

Comment: *Hall of cats* is indeed a strange expression, but one way to make sense of it would be to take it to mean a hall **full of** cats; such an interpretation is not available for *hall of cat*.